# How can I use attributes with dots and the at character?

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'm using WSO2 Stream Processor and I need to use a stream that have attributes with '.' and '@'.

There are any way to use them? For example replace that values in incoming events or something like that. This is because my incoming events have some fields with '.' and '@' and editor do not process them.

I tryied to use these streams:

```
define stream test (name string, @timestamp string);
define stream test2 (core.pct  double, system.info string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @ and . in the attributes is restricted in Siddhi because these characters are being used to identify special Siddhi structs(eg:@source, @map, @annotation) at Siddhi grammar level.

What is the input format you receive the events. You can map the incoming events to the streams to avoid these special characters. Please refer the [Siddhi Source Mapper](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/query-guide/#source-mapper) documentation for more details.

Comment: My input format is : `{"@timestamp":"Oct 9, 2019 @ 12:30:35.559", "name":"test1"}`. And I have tried the mapper, but I will have 250+ fields/attributes  and it is impossible to map all of them. And if I do not map all of them I loose that data.